# Allocating stock to a sales order using a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, database-cursor

I am using MS SQL Server 2014. I am trying to allocate stock to a sales order. The sales order can have multple lines, and stock codes can be repeated.The stock being allocated has a unique reference for each occurance.
I am looking to allocate stock to a stock code line by line, once the allocation has been ccompleted, the @allocation temp table is updatted, so when the cursor next runs it only selects the free stock and the stock allocated is ignored.
I have not added this element as yet, but when I try and run the code as it stands, I receive the following error

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 67 Invalid object name 'ctee'.

Any help on why the cte is invalid would be most apprecicated.

The code I have is shown below.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[@allocation]') is not null
 DROP TABLE [dbo].[@allocation]
 declare @RESULT AS TABLE(COR_UNIQUE VARCHAR(20),COR_PART_ONLY varchar(16),COR_OUR_NUMBER  varchar(16),COR_QTY_ORDERED   decimal(18,5) );
 declare @allocation AS TABLE(L_U VARCHAR(20),C_U VARCHAR(20),L_PART varchar(16),L_PHY DECIMAL(18,5),R_T DECIMAL(18,5),ORD_RUN DECIMAL(18,5),T_L DECIMAL(18,5),FINAL_T_L DECIMAL(18,5));
DECLARE @COR_UNIQUE AS VARCHAR(20),@COR_PART_ONLY AS varchar(16),@COR_OUR_NUMBER  AS varchar(16),@COR_QTY_ORDERED as decimal(18,5);
DECLARE @L_U  AS VARCHAR(20),@C_U AS VARCHAR(20),@L_PART AS varchar(16),@L_PHY AS decimal(18,5),@R_T AS DECIMAL(18,5),@ORD_RUN AS DECIMAL(18,5),@T_L AS DECIMAL(18,5),@FINAL_T_L AS DECIMAL(18,5);

DECLARE cursor_results CURSOR FOR

with   ctea(COR_UNIQUE,COR_PART_ONLY,COR_OUR_NUMBER,COR_QTY_ORDERED)
  as
  (
 SELECT  [COR_UNIQUE]
      ,[COR_PART_ONLY]
      ,[COR_OUR_NUMBER]
      ,[COR_QTY_ORDERED]
     
  FROM [RMC_ASC_TEST].[dbo].[ASC_COR_TBL]
  where COR_OUR_NUMBER_N ='8215258'
  and [COR_UNIQUE] = '437145'
  )
  
 select COR_UNIQUE,COR_PART_ONLY,COR_OUR_NUMBER,COR_QTY_ORDERED
from ctea
--left join cte WITH (NOLOCK) ON LOT_PART_ONLY = COR_PART_ONLY
--where @COR_UNIQUE = COR_UNIQUE
 
OPEN cursor_results;
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_results into @COR_UNIQUE,@COR_PART_ONLY,@COR_OUR_NUMBER,@COR_QTY_ORDERED  ;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
WITH CTW(L_UN,F_T_L)
AS
(
SELECT L_U AS L_UN
      ,SUM( FINAL_T_L) AS F_T_L
       FROM @allocation
       GROUP BY L_U
),
 CTEB(LOT_UNIQUE_B,LOT_PART_ONLY_B,LOT_PHYSICAL_B,LOT_KIT_ALLOCATIONS_B,RUNNING_TOTAL_B)
  AS
  (SELECT LOT_UNIQUE,LOT_PART_ONLY,LOT_PHYSICAL- F_T_L AS LOT_PHYSICAL ,LOT_KIT_ALLOCATIONS,
sum(LOT_PHYSICAL) over (order by LOT_EXPIRY_DATE) AS RUNNING_TOTAL
FROM [dbo].[ASC_LOT_TBL]
LEFT JOIN CTW WITH (NOLOCK) ON L_UN =LOT_UNIQUE
 where LOT_PART_ONLY ='105165'
 ),
 CTEC(L_U,C_U,L_PART,L_PHY,R_T,ORD_RUN,T_L)
 AS
 (
SELECT LOT_UNIQUE_B AS L_U,@COR_UNIQUE as C_U,LOT_PART_ONLY_B AS L_PART,LOT_PHYSICAL_B AS L_PHY,RUNNING_TOTAL_B AS R_T, RUNNING_TOTAL_B-@COR_QTY_ORDERED AS ORD_RUN,
case
when RUNNING_TOTAL_B-@COR_QTY_ORDERED <=0 then LOT_PHYSICAL_B
WHEN RUNNING_TOTAL_B- LOT_PHYSICAL_B >= 0  AND LOT_PHYSICAL_B - (@COR_QTY_ORDERED-RUNNING_TOTAL_B) >= 0 THEN LOT_PHYSICAL_B -(RUNNING_TOTAL_B-@COR_QTY_ORDERED)


ELSE 0
end as T_L

 FROM CTEB
  left join @RESULT  ON @COR_PART_ONLY =LOT_PART_ONLY_B
  where LOT_PART_ONLY_B ='105165'
),
  ctee(L_U,C_U,L_PART,L_PHY,R_T,ORD_RUN,T_L,FINAL_T_L)
as
(select L_U,C_U,L_PART,L_PHY,R_T,ORD_RUN,T_L,FINAL_T_L from @allocation)
INSERT INTO @allocation VALUES (@L_U,@C_U,@L_PART,@L_PHY ,@R_T,@ORD_RUN ,@T_L ,@FINAL_T_L)select * from ctee
--SELECT L_U,C_U,L_PART,L_PHY,R_T,ORD_RUN,T_L,
--CASE
--WHEN T_L <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE T_L END AS FINAL_T_L
--FROM CTEC

--INSERT INTO @RESULT VALUES (@COR_UNIQUE,@COR_PART_ONLY,@COR_OUR_NUMBER,@COR_QTY_ORDERED);
  INSERT INTO @allocation VALUES( @L_U,@C_U,@L_PART,@L_PHY ,@R_T,@ORD_RUN ,@T_L ,@FINAL_T_L);
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_results into @COR_UNIQUE,@COR_PART_ONLY,@COR_OUR_NUMBER,@COR_QTY_ORDERED ;
END
CLOSE cursor_results;
DEALLOCATE cursor_results;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a CTE, it exists *only* for the life of the batch.

In your code you define `ctee` as the last of several CTEs on line 62 but then immediately do an `insert into` on line 65 - that's the *end* of that batch.

The following `select * from ctee` is a *new* batch for which `ctee` is not defined.